# SQL Column after insert read only without trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, readonly, create-table

I have to create two columns (creator, creation date), which is after insert readonly. These two fields can't be changed after the insert. I know that is posible with sql-triggers to solve this requirement. but think this is not a comfortable solutuion.

Is there a solution to solve my "problem" with in the `Create-Table-Statemant`

Comment: **NO** you don't have such option in `Sql Server`. Simple `Update Trigger` will work for you

Comment: Can you prevent people accessing the table directly and use stored procedures for all activity?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. i dont "like" triggers and use it only there is not another solution. But in this case, i have to use trigger. 
thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Maybe the Column permission will work for you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/restrict-update-on-certain-columns-only-allow-stored-procedure-to-update-those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Column permission will work for you.

```
DENY UPDATE ON dbo.MyTable (Creator, CreationDate) TO SampleRole;
```

Answer (score 1):

No and maybe yes :)

This can't be done with a single table, but it is possible to create another table and create a FK to it. With a proper security in place (inserts into the main table only through a stored procedure signed with a certificate and denying modifications to referenced table to everyone except a user created from the same cert, eg), this will make it rather difficult for someone to modify it. Of course, an admin/owner user can't be stopped.

LMK if you wish me to expand the answer with the code.