# sql trigger -> where did it get triggered from?

Tags: sql, triggers

We have an sql-table with products in it.
We need to know how a certain column is mutated, since we made this impossible but it still does get changed.

So say product 'APPLETREE' is once created with length 3 mtr.
This 3 mtr may never be changed. And still sometimes it does get!

To find out why we created a trigger on table products to write a log-file with columns
productnr , oldlength value, newlength value, date, time, user.

This all works fine. We get the info.

But preferably we would also know where the trigger got fired from (which stored procedure or sql job)

Is there a way to get the 'path' from which te trigger was fired ?

I could not find documentation about this

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274698/sql-column-after-insert-read-only-without-trigger or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098759/sql-server-2005-setting-a-column-as-readonly

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: sql server 2012